# How do I send emails using a Perl script

Tags: perl, email

This is for my last exam, so i would be very grateful if someone helped me.

I've been told to write Perl script for sending e-mails to many users. 
It`s supposed to work like this:

1) The script reads an .html document that is supposed to be the body of the email.

2) It reads .txt document that contains all the e-mail addresses (divided by ";") that the email should be sent to. There may be hundreds, thousands e-mail addresses.

3) The script should somehow read the SMTP settings for sending the e-mail.

I`m looking forward to anyone's answer.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @yko: from your link 'Larry now uses "Perl"  to signify the language': I don't see what's wrong with: Perl (language) script (which is then run by perl, the interpreter)

Comment: @Matteo, in original topic all letters was capitalized. See edit history and also sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @yko — By "capitalized" do you mean "written in all-caps"? "Perl" is capitalized as I understand the term.

Comment: Sorry, Goran, but this sounds a lot like you're spamming people.

Comment: @Quentin, you are right. I deleted my comment because it's actually wrong and confusing people.

Comment: @TLP - It sure does :), but i swear to god that it is an assignment that the professor gave us. `Couse we have this exam that is not conducted with tests, but every student needs to write a perl script to pass it. So if you somehow can, then please help me. I have a deadline `till sunday.

Comment: @Goran I think your task is to write script, not to find people who will write it for you. If you just google for `perl send mail` you'll find much info on that. Btw, which school and (if it's not secret) what's your professor name?

Comment: @yko i`ve been googling it for an hour now but i couldn`t find something exactly like this. And i would have written the script myself if i were to do programming in my life, but since i go to economics college and this is just one subject, i thought of asking for some help. I`m from Spain btw, so i don`t think that you would know the school nor the professor..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example on Robert Maldons blog. Check http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2006/10/sending-email-through-google-smtp-from.html

Comment: thanks a lot man, you`ve rescued me from hours of search.. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I am not going to write the code for you - you will benefit so much more if you attempted to write the code yourself.

1) You need to [read](http://www.pageresource.com/cgirec/ptut14.htm) the "body" file and store it for use later in the script.

2) Again read the contents of the "email address" file, you may need to use the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function to seperate the emails addresses. Store these in an array, perhaps you may want to validate each email address before adding it to the array.

3) For every entry in the array - send the email. For sending the emails you could use the following module [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/SMTP.pm)

Answer (score 1):

look for Net::SMTP::SSL
It has everything with the code snippet 
You only need to add syntax